# How to filter list by specific item in list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a data which is coming from the server and it can be **null** or **empty**. I tried to filter basic to avoid **null** code and replace with **empty**.

```
fun filterMovieItemList(unfilteredList: List<MovieItem>): List<MovieItemModel> {
    val movieItemModelList = mutableListOf<MovieItemModel>()
    if (unfilteredList.isNotEmpty()) {
        unfilteredList.forEachIndexed { _, movieItem ->
            val movieDetails = movieItem.movieDetails
            if (movieDetails != null && !movieDetails.name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val icon = movieDetails.iconUrl ?: "xyz"
                movieItemModelList.add(
                    MovieItemModel(
                        movieDetails.name,
                        icon,
                        movieDetails.summary ?: "",
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
    return movieItemModelList
}
```

Now I am trying to make more readable to use `map`, but I am not sure this is correct way so please free to suggest new and improve version.

```
fun filterMapMovieItemList(unfilteredList: List<MovieItem>): List<MovieItemModel> {
    return unfilteredList.mapNotNull { data ->
        data.movieDetails?.name?.let {
            data.movieDetails
        }
    }.map { movieItem ->
        val icon = movieItem.iconUrl ?: "xyz"
        MovieItemModel(
            name = movieItem.name ?: "",
            icon = icon,
            summary = movieItem.summary ?: ""
        )
    }
}
```

Is there any idomatic way to filter this kind of data with the help of any other method? I know only about `map`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi optimise the code by using `asSequence()`

```
fun filterMapMovieItemList(unfilteredList: List<MovieItem>): List<MovieItemModel> {
    return unfilteredList
        .asSequence()
        .mapNotNull { it.movieDetails }
        .filterNot { it.name.isNullOrEmpty() }
        .map { movieItem ->
            val icon = movieItem.iconUrl ?: "xyz"
            MovieItemModel(
                name = movieItem.name.orEmpty(),
                icon = icon,
                summary = movieItem.summary.orEmpty()
            )
        }.toList()
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the code in your `mapNotNull` block by using `takeIf` function, which returns the value if it satisfies the given predicate.

```
fun filterMapMovieItemList(unfilteredList: List<MovieItem>): List<MovieItemModel> {
    return unfilteredList.mapNotNull { it.movieDetails?.takeIf { details -> !details.name.isNullOrEmpty() } }
        .map { movieDetails ->
            val icon = movieDetails.iconUrl ?: "xyz"
            MovieItemModel(
                name = movieDetails.name ?: "",
                icon = icon,
                summary = movieDetails.summary ?: ""
            )
        }
}
```